# How to get store admin email address and name in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, configuration, stores

I want replacement of the following in magento 2

```
/* Name */
Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_sales/name'); 
/* Email */
Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_sales/email');
```

or similar to getting current store admin name and email.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try the below code -

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $request;
    protected $scopeConfig;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
){
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->request = $request;
}

public function execute()
{
    $email = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_support/email',ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    $name  = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_support/name',ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

    echo $email;echo "<br/>";
    echo $name;echo "<br/>";

    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->renderLayout();
}
```

}

Comment: I got information related to customer how to get regarding sales ??

Comment: got it replacing 
'trans_email/ident_support/email' 
with
'trans_email/ident_general/email'

Comment: Thanks
Accepted.....!!

Answer (score 0):

Use DI instead of direct Object manager use

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $scopeConfig = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface');
    $email = $scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_support/email',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```