# How to get store admin email address and name in Magento 2 in a Block?

Tags: magento2, blocks, email

I would like to know the equivalent Magento 2 code to give me access to display these values on the frontend.

```
/* Name */
Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_sales/name'); 

/* Email */
Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_sales/email');
```

[How to get store admin email address and name in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109463/how-to-get-store-admin-email-address-and-name-in-magento-2)

I have seen this solution but I do not understand the need for a Controller/Index in order to display values such as Store Email Address.

Answer (score 13):

You have to create first block and defined function inside block for getting store name and store email,
**inside construct method pass `ScopeConfigInterface` object**

Create the method `getStoreName()`, `getStoreEmail()`

```
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        .......
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig        
    ) {
        .....
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        .....
    }
    
    public function getStorename()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'trans_email/ident_sales/name',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }

 public function getStoreEmail()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'trans_email/ident_sales/email',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
```

Call function inside your template file, like echo **`$block->getStoreEmail()`** and **`echo $block->getStoreName();`**

Comment: If your extending from AbstractBlock, you'll already have `$this->_scopeConfig` defined.

Comment: What if we have to get the same in admin ? actually i am working to trigger cancel order mail in which i have to sent sender details(name and sender mail)...What if we have to get the same in admin ? actually i am working to trigger cancel order mail in which i have to sent sender details(name and sender mail)...i am using multiple websites.

Answer (score 2):

Use these methods in your block class:

```
    public function getSalesEmail()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'trans_email/ident_sales/email',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }

    public function getSalesName()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'trans_email/ident_sales/name',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
```

Call from the template like `echo $block->getSalesEmail();`

Comment: What if we have to get the same in admin ? actually i am working to trigger cancel order mail in which i have to sent sender details(name and sender mail)...i am using multiple websites.

Answer (score 0):

> use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

Then

> $this->scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_support/email',
>   ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);